# Linear Algebra: showing that $\lambda x + y \in Y \Rightarrow Y \subset X$ is a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm having trouble trying to prove the following exercise:

**Prove that $Y \subset X$ is a subspace if and only if $\lambda x + y \in Y$ for all $x,y \in Y$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{K}$.**

I did a proof for the first part $( Y \subset X $ is a subspace $\Rightarrow \lambda x + y \in Y )$:

By the closure of scalar multiplication: $\lambda x = z \in Y$

By the closure of the addition: $z+y \in Y$

Therefore, $\lambda x + y \in Y$ for all $x,y \in Y$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{K} $.

But I'm stuck on how to prove the other way $( \lambda x + y \in Y \Rightarrow Y \subset X $ is a subspace $ )$. I don't even know how to start.

Comment: How do yo define subspace? -- Actually, the claim is false because it wrongly suggests that $Y:=\emptyset$ is a subspace

Comment: The empty set is a counterexample. But the proposition becomes true if $Y$ is not empty.

Comment: You must add the requirement that $\;Y\neq\emptyset\;$ , otherwise the claim is false, as already explained in the comments above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated, the claim is false because $Y = \emptyset$ is not a subspace, but does satisfy the condition. If you additionally assume that $Y \neq \emptyset$, it is true. To show this, first show that $0 \in Y$ by taking an arbitrary element $x \in Y$ and looking at $-1 \cdot x + x$. Then show closure under addition by taking $\lambda = 1$ and show closure under scalar multiplication by taking $y = 0$.